# why c++ allowing private member access of instance in member function definition?

Tags: c++

Stock is a class which has private data member named total_val.

```
const Stock & Stock::topval(const Stock & s) const 
{ 
    if (s.total_val > total_val) 
        return s;           
    else 
        return *this;       
}
```

is this program correct ?
in my intution we should not be allowed to access the private member here

```
if (s.total_val > total_val)
```

i think `s.total_val` should not be allowed

please explain to me

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is correct.

> A private member of a class can only be accessed by the members and friends of that class, **regardless of whether the members are on the same or different instances**.

In your case you have a member on a different instance, so it should be okay.